# Dockerize Java Web App: Maven + Tomcat + Docker

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, docker

Tenho visto frequentemente diversos tutoriais do **docker** parar subir serviços "prontos", porém vejo poucas instruções relacionadas em como utilizá-lo dentro do fluxo de desenvolvimento. Principalmente em **linguagens compiladas** como exemplo o **Java** que exige um passo adicional de compilação que ao contrário das **linguagens dinâmicas** não exigem esse passo.

Como eu poderia organizar o meu **workflow de desenvolvimento** utilizando o Docker em todo ciclo de vida? Tanto na utilização de um **container para compilar meu código**, rodando o **"mvn clean install"**, quanto **no deploy no servidor de aplicação** (aqui no caso o tomcat). Eu deveria montar 2 containers um para cada passo? Como ficaria as dependências entre esses dois containers já que o segundo responsável pelo deploy só poderá entrar em ação após o container de compilação ter feito seu trabalho e gerado o artefato **(.war)**?

Um próximo passo (e não menos importante) seria criar uma integração da execução desses passos com uma **IDE (Netbeans ou Eclipse por exemplo)** para que este fluxo de desenvolvimento com Docker ficasse transparente durante o processo.

## Resumindo:

- Como ficaria o fluxo?
- Como ficariam os Dockerfile?
- Como organizar a ordem de execução? (Utilizando shellscript, talvez ou caberiam em um docker-compose?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A ideia é que eu possa usar esta solução em qualquer projeto que utilize **"Maven + Tomcat"** colocando os seguintes arquivos na raiz do projeto seguindo os passos abaixo.

No exemplo utilizei o projeto que segue disponível no github:
https://github.com/rogeriofonseca/docker-java-tomcat-maven

**1 -** Estrutura de arquivos para configuração do Docker

```
docker-compose.yml
dockerfiles/
├── Dockerfile-apache
├── Dockerfile-maven
├── Dockerfile-mysql
└── tomcat-users.xml
scripts/
└── entrypointscript.sh
```

**2 -** docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=projeto_jpa
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  maven:
      build:
        context: dockerfiles
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-maven
      volumes:
        - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
        - $PWD:/usr/src/mymaven
      volumes_from:
        - tomcat
  tomcat:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-apache
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
```

**2.1 Dockerfile-apache**

```
FROM tomcat:8.0

ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY tomcat-users.xml  $CATALINA_HOME/conf/
VOLUME $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
```

**2.2 Dockerfile-maven**

```
FROM openjdk:7-jdk

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
  && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
    | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
  && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

VOLUME "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"
WORKDIR /usr/src/mymaven
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/mymaven/scripts/entrypointscript.sh"]
```

**2.3 Dockerfile-mysql**

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=projeto_jpa

expose 3306:3306
```

**2.4 Um ponto de atenção para este aqui. Ele é responsável por compilar e copiar todos artefatos para o tomcat.**
*No meu caso tenho um projeto que tem vários módulos, então o resultado final terá mais de um **.war**, por este motivo o **"find"** buscando em todo diretório e sub-diretórios.*

Arquivo: ***scripts/entrypoint.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn clean install -e -f  /usr/src/mymaven  &&
find /usr/src/mymaven/target -name "*.war" -exec cp '{}' /usr/local/tomcat/webapps \;
```

**2.5 tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,manager, manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

## **# Comandos úteis:**

1 - Para subir os containers basta executar na raiz do projeto o comando:

```
$ docker-compose build --no-cache && docker-compose up -d
```

2 - Para recompilar após efetuar alguma alteração no código **Java** basta executar apenas o container específico do **maven**. Ele fará o papel de recompilar o código e copiar os artefatos para o **volume** compartilhado entre os dois containers.

```
$ docker-compose run maven
```

*Ps.: O próximo passo será adequar este fluxo no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento integrando o fluxo com a minha IDE. Mas isto é pauta para outro tópico.*

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz algo semelhante para demostrar, modestamente, compotências técnicas [[GitHub Pssilva: 2017](https://github.com/pssilva/paas-docker)] (trabalho em progresso). Mas adaptei para contribuir com a comunidade e assim tentar responder as dúvidas acima.

**Como ficaria o fluxo?** 
Fluxo de trabalho geralmente é uma coisa subjetiva, logo descreverei um fluxo genérico que usei no meu ambiente: 
1. Ambiente Docker no VirtualBox:

Assumindo que já tenha um VM com o Ubuntu `16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xeru)` com o GIT, e o servidor SSH instalados e apropriadamente configurados. Então, podemos instalar o docker.

```
$ssh [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST] -p 22
$sudo su
#echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-$(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
#apt-cache policy docker-engine
#apt-get update
#apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-$(lsb_release -cs)
#reboot
$ssh [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST] -p 22
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install docker-engine
$sudo service docker start
$sudo service docker status
$sudo gpasswd -a $(whoami) docker
$exit
$ssh [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST] -p 22
```

---

2. Testar o Docker: `Helo Word`.

```
$ssh [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST] -p 22
$docker run oskarhane/hello echo "Hello, let me out of here"
$docker ps -a
```

Pronto, após testar podemos limpar os conteiners e as imagens.

```
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)
```

---

3. Criar o projeto Spring Boot

3.1 Instalar os plugins na IDE

No meu caso eu uso a IDE Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
E os principais plugins que uso são:  
 
  - The Spring Tool Suite™ (STS) 
 
  - m2e - Maven integration for Eclipse 
 
  - Gradle IDE & Enide Gradle for Eclipse in one operation.

3.2 Criar o projeto:

Para este teste aqui, usando o plugin STS, crie um projeto como este da imagem:

[image: Spring Boot]

Importante, veja o Location: /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject 
Será onde clonaremos o repositório.

[image: Spring Boot Dependencias]

3.3 Edite o arquivo: /microservicesSpringProject/src/main/java/br/com/microservicesSpringProject/MicroservicesSpringProjectApplication.java

Deixando conforme abaxo:

```
package br.com.microservicesSpringProject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class MicroservicesSpringProjectApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "My Microserver: Stackoverflow";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MicroservicesSpringProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

3.4 Build Aplicação:

```
$cd /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject
$mvn package && java -jar target/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Apenas para testar a aplicação, acesso o link: `localhost:8080`. 
IMPORTANTE: o arquivo: `/Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject/target/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

---

4. Criar o repositório do projeto

4.1 Na Virtual Machine, assumindo que você já tenha configurado seu servidor git [[Git: 2017 - b](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor-Configurando-o-Servidor)]

```
$ssh [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST] -p 22
$mkdir -p /opt/microservicesSpringProject.git
$cd /opt/microservicesSpringProject.git
$git --bare init  --shared=[DEV_GROUP_PERMISSION]
$chmod 0777 -Rf /opt/microservicesSpringProject.git
$chown [SEU_USER] -Rf /opt/microservicesSpringProject.git
```

4.2 Na máquina Host, máquina física.

```
$cd /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject
$chmod 0777 /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject
$git init
$echo "#[NOME_PROJETO]" > README.md
$git add .
$git commit -m 'initial commit'
$git remote add origin ssh://[SEU_USER]@[IP_SERVER]:22/opt/microservicesSpringProject.git
$git push origin master
```

---

5. Criar a sua própria imagem docker: Criar o arquivo Dockerfile

Aqui podemos responder: **Como ficariam os Dockerfile?**. 
 
O mesmo arquivo Dockerfile pode ser reutilizado para gerar multiplas images. 
O arquivo dockerfile [[Docker: 2017 - a](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/)] pode ser feito de várias maneiras, a o formato a seguir me atendeu [[Docker: 2017 - b](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerfile-examples)]:

```
# escape=\ (backslash)
# My Microservices
#
# VERSION               0.0.1
# AUTHOR                Paulo Sergio da Silva
# EMAIL                 pss1suporte@gmail.com

FROM    ubuntu
VOLUME /tmp

LABEL Description="This image is used to build a application whith Architecture Microservices." Vendor="PSSILVA Products" Version="1.0"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y inotify-tools apache2 openssh-server git
RUN apt-get clean all
RUN apt-get install -y default-jre
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jre
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository ppa:maxmind/ppa && apt-get update && apt-get -y install libmaxminddb0 libmaxminddb-dev mmdb-bin
RUN apt-get clean all
RUN apt-get update

CMD ["mkdir","-p","/opt/spring-1.5.1.RELEASE"]
#COPY spring-1.5.1.RELEASE/* /opt/spring-1.5.1.RELEASE/

#CMD ["ln","-s","./opt/spring-1.5.1.RELEASE/bash/spring","/etc/bash_completion.d/spring"]
#CMD ["ln","-s","./opt/spring-1.5.1.RELEASE/zsh/_spring","/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_spring"]

ADD microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /root/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /root/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /root/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" ]


#CMD ["java","-jar","/root/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Apenas para versionamento, crie o arquivo Dockerfile na pasta /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject/docker-image

```
$mkdir -p /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject/docker-image/spring-1.5.1.RELEASE
$cd /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject/docker-image
$vim Dockerfile
```

Na Virtual Machine, crie o arquivo e construa (build) a imagem docker.

```
$ssh [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST] -p 22
$mkdir -p ~/projects/microservicesSpringProject/docker-image/spring-1.5.1.RELEASE
$cd ~/projects/microservicesSpringProject/docker-image

//O comando abaixo envia a aplicação Spring Boot (.jar) da Máquina Física - MF para a Máquina Virtual.
$scp  -P22 -v -r -C  /Users/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject/target/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar [SEU_USER]@[IP_HOST]:/home/[SEU_USER]/projects/microservicesSpringProject/docker-image

$vim Dockerfile
$docker build -t ubuntu:MicroservicesSpringBoot .
```

Após o processamento acima, podemos verificar as imagens docker instaladas:

```
$docker images
```

Agora, ainda na Virtual Machine, podemos executar a aplicação Spring Boot:

```
$docker run -e "JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n" -p 8080:8080 -p 5005:5005 -t -i ubuntu:MicroservicesSpringBoot java -jar /root/microservicesSpringProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Após o comando acima, podemos acessar a aplicação Spring Boot rodando no container Docker de dentro da VM acessando o link: `[IP_HOST]:8080`.

Podemos entrar no container e trabalhar no servidor da seguinte forma:

```
 $docker run -t -i ubuntu:MicroservicesSpringBoot /bin/bash
```

---

6. Enviar a imgem Docker: hub.docker.com

Considerando que você já tenha uma conta no `hub.docker.com` [[hub.docker: 2017](https://hub.docker.com/)]. E tendo em mente que reutilização aumenta a produtividade, é indicado fortemente como boa prática temos que enviar o container docker para o meu repositório.

```
$docker login
$docker tag [IMAGE_ID] [LOGIN_HUB_DOCKER]/[NOME_REPO]:latest
$docker push LOGIN_HUB_DOCKER]/[NOME_REPO]
```

---

7. Automação do Processo.

Aqui, procuro responder as eguintes perguntas: **Como organizar a ordem de execução? (Utilizando shellscript, talvez ou caberiam em um docker-compose?)**
Mas infelizmente tratarei de foma mais conceitual do que empírica abordando o assunto Integração Contínua - IC [[Stackoverflow - CI: 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28608015/3542189)]. Por não ter muita confiança no pouco que sei, estou buscando implementas as orientações e boas práticas [[Alan Mark Berg: 2015](https://ebooks-it.org/1784390089-ebook.htm)] usados no ambiente Jenkins.

---

Acredito que seja isso. Obrigado pela pergunta e por isso, pela oportunidade em aprender e contribuir.

---

#### Referência:

[Sébastien Goasguen: 2016], **[Docker Cookbook](http://www.allitebooks.com/docker-cookbook/)**: SOLUTIONS AND EXAMPLES FOR BUILDING DISTRIBUTED APPLICATIONS. 
[Alan Mark Berg: 2015], **[Jenkins Continuous Integration Cookbook](https://ebooks-it.org/1784390089-ebook.htm)**: Second Edition 
[Docker: 2017 - a], Disponível em: **[Dockerfile Best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/)**. Acesso: 01 Abr 2017
[Docker: 2017 - b], Disponível em: **[Dockerfile Examples](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/dockerfile-examples)**. Acesso: 01 Abr 2017
[Docker: 2017 - c], Disponível em: **[PaaS Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)**: Image Docker criada com a intensão de implementar um Plataforma as a Service - PaaS. Acesso: 02 Abr 2017
[Git: 2017 - a], Disponível em: **[Git Essencial Obtendo um Repositório Git](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Essencial-Obtendo-um-Reposit%C3%B3rio-Git)**. Acesso: 01 Abr 2017
[Git: 2017 - b], Disponível em: **[Git no Servidor - Configurando o Servidor](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-no-Servidor-Configurando-o-Servidor)**. Acesso: 01 Abr 2017
[Christian Posta: 2016], Disponível em: **[Microservices for Java Developers](https://developers.redhat.com/promotions/microservices-for-java-developers)**: A Hands-on Introduction to Frameworks and Containers. Acesso: 01 Abr 2017
[Markus Eisele: 2016], Disponível em: **[Modern Java EE Design Patterns](https://developers.redhat.com/promotions/distributed-javaee-architecture)**: Building Scalable Architecture for Sustainable Enterprise Development. 
[Spring: 2017], Disponível em: **[Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)**: Site com tutorial. Acesso: 02 Abr 2017
[GitHub Pssilva: 2017], Disponível em: **[GitHub Pssilva](https://github.com/pssilva/paas-docker)**: Meu modesto repositório GitHub. Acesso: 02 Abr 2017
[hub.docker: 2017], Disponível em: **[Hub Docker](https://hub.docker.com/)**: repositório Docker. Acesso: 02 Abr 2017
[Stackoverflow - CI: 2017], Disponível em: **[Continuous Integration - CI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28608015/3542189)**: repositório Docker. Acesso: 02 Abr 2017

Comment: Você recomenda instalar um servidor de git? Por que? Qual a integração com o build feito na IDE? Por que o dockerfile em comandos comentados (#COPY)?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, primeiro: o servidor git entendo que seja boa prática, e é essencial na automação e gerenciamento das releases no build no container docker. Os comandos comentados no dockerfile é a instalação do [Spring Boot CLI](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/). Que também é importante para automação dos processo de build e testes de integração. Tem outras maneira para instalar, mas fiz desta forma para ter mais controle. E que julguei deixar comentados porque poderia fugir do escopo da resposta.

Comment: Tua resposta foi bem extensa, mas ainda assim não consegui identificar a seguinte necessidade: "Um próximo passo (e não menos importante) seria criar uma integração da execução desses passos com uma IDE (Netbeans ou Eclipse por exemplo) para que este fluxo de desenvolvimento com Docker ficasse transparente durante o processo."

Comment: Passos como criar a imagem docker não podem ser manuais, por exemplo.

Comment: Porque a pergunta foi essa sobre o fluxo. Por isso achei melhor me concentrar no fluxo.  Mas no **7. Automação do Processo** abordei de forma conceitual a melhor forma de integrar o fluxo usando Jenkins.

Comment: Criar a imagem é para demostrar o poder que se tem para criar um imagem. Logo depois indico: **6. Enviar a imagem Docker: hub.docker.com**. Com isso usar a imagem já pronta na automação quando necessário.

Comment: Pelo pouco que sei, as atividades de DevOps é preparar o ambiente de forma que os processos automatizados corram transparentes ficando fora do escopo de trabalho de desenvolvimento. E desenvolvedor apenas acompanha os scripts rodando sem interferir muito.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Me deu um caminho.

Comment: @RafaelWeber, OK ! Mas pretendo melhorar a resposta. Assim que terminar aqui uns testes no ambiente Jenkins. E teste de integração entre containers docker.

Answer (score 2):

No atual projeto do qual participo estou usando a seguinte estrutura:

```
raiz-projeto/
  frontend/
    ...
    package.json 
  backend/
    ...
    pom.xml
  infra/
    dockerfiles/
      db.Dockerfile
      app-server.Dockerfile
      web-server.Dockerfile
      ...
    helpers.sh
  docker-compose.yml
  dev.docker-compose.yml
  test.docker-compose.yaml
  .alias
```

Como os nomes sugerem:

```
1 o código da api rest reside em 'backend';

2. o código da spa reside em 'frontend';

3. boa parte do código adicional relacionado a configuração do ambiente onde a solução roda reside em 'infra';

4. em 'docker-compose.yml', encontra-se a configuração dos containeres mais próxima possível de como estará na produção, em se fazendo necessário poderá haver um arquivo de extensão Dockerfile para montagem da imagem daquele container/serviço específico.

5. 'dev.docker-compose.yml' contem a configuração necessária para rodar um ambiente mínimo para desenvolvimento nas tecnologias envolvidas, por exemplo: 
  5a. ambiente nodejs para desenvolvimento de frontend;
  5b. ambiente maven para desenvolvimento do backend;

6. 'test.docker-compose.yml' contem a configuração necesária para execução de testes automatizado, seja mocando serviços inteiros para prover dependências aos módulos sob teste (um backend para um frontend, um banco de testes para um backend, um ldap para um backend, etc)

7. por fim, nao menos importante, '.alias' é um compêndio de linux aliases a serem usado dentro daquele projeto e facilmente configurável através de 'source ./.alias'. Dentre outras coisas pode conter um apelido para a linha de comando quase sempre necessário quando se trabalha com docker, exemplo:
  7a. alias draf='docker rm `docker ps -aq` -f'
  7b. alias dcr='docker-compose run'
  7c. alias dev-backend='dcr -f dev.docker-compose.yml backend /bin/bash'
```

É uma estrutura em processo de otimização, de forma que está sempre sofrendo adaptações.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vou partir do pressuposto que você possui uma IDE e o mínimo de recursos para compilar seu projeto Java nela.

Uma das mudanças que eu proponho é usar o [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) e utilizar o Tomcat embarcado, o que vai simplificar o seu deploy, podendo rodar sua aplicação com um simples `java -jar app.jar`.

### Dockerizar a aplicação

Dentro do seu projeto Spring Boot, criamos o Dockerfile (`src/main/docker/Dockerfile`):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
VOLUME /tmp

ADD *.jar app.jar

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

Para construir a imagem docker é necessário adicionar um plugin ao Maven.

### Construir uma imagem Docker com Maven

No `pom.xml` você deve adicionar o seguinte:

```
<properties>
   <docker.image.prefix>myorganization</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <forceTags>true</forceTags>
                <imageTags>
                    <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                    <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                </imageTags>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Este trecho possui 3 configurações:

- O nome da imagem, que resultará em myorganization/myproject
- O diretório onde deve ser encontrado Dockerfile
- Os arquivos (resources) a copiar do diretório de compilação para construir a imagem docker (neste caso somente o arquivo .jar é necessário)

Para fazer o build da imagem docker, você deve executar o seguinte comando:

```
mvn package docker:build -DpushImage
```

Você não precisa fazer o push para rodar a imagem criada localmente. Mas ele vai te permitir disponibilizar a imagem no Dockerhub, facilitando o deploy automatizado em provedores de cloud. Para tanto, você deve alterar a configuração `docker.image.prefix` para o seu próprio docker ID.

### Executando a aplicação com docker

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t myorganization/myproject
```

Comment: Murillo Goulart, obrigado pela resposta.  

A ideia do SpringBoot, do tomcat embarcado é excelente porém nem sempre é possível alterar a arquitetura do projeto, muitas vezes por questões práticas ou corporativas. A ideia da inclusão de configurações docker no pom.xml também não me atraem pois a ideia é que a solução atenda a qualquer projeto que utilize maven + tomcat sem necessidade de alterações adicionais.

Comment: E Finalmente, eu não consideraria efetuar a compilação na própria máquina, pois em um cenário de implantação do código no cliente, seria interessante que a aplicação/container fosse staless e totalmente autônoma. Para fins de deploy existiria um container que baixaria o código e efetuaria a etapa de compilação no próprio cliente. Através disso seria possível efetuar a atualização de um deploy rodando apenas um container específico.

Comment: @RogérioFonseca com o pushImage, a imagem é publicada no dockerhub, podendo ser facilmente automatizado o deploy a partir disso.

Comment: Mas a cada atualização do sistema ficaria dependente de um push image no docker hub, não? Da forma que pensei bastaria um push em um repositório git e o container baixaria do git. Compreende?