# objetos compartilhando a mesma cópia de uma variável

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, design-pattern, classes-abstratas

O objetivo é colocar em prática os conceitos contidos que estou aprendendo em [MALA GUPTA, 2015](http://www.allitebooks.com/ocp-java-se-7-programmer-ii-certification-guide/). Então, a forma que encontrei em contribuir é solicitar à comunidade em implementar na prática os conceitos. Assim quem se interessar e desejar contribuir e querer demostrar os conhecimentos está lançado o desafio.

Então, para contextualizar, é o seguinte: assumindo que seja necessário implementar uma Class Abstrata:

- Identificar quando e como aplicar classes abstratas
- Construa classes e subclasses abstratas Java

Quando eu faço com que os objetos compartilhem a mesma cópia de uma variável e quando os forneço com sua própria cópia individual separada? 
E qual a melhor forma de implementar na prática, em uma aplicação?

#### Referência:

[MALA GUPTA, 2015], **[OCP Java SE 7 Programmer II Certification Guide](http://www.allitebooks.com/ocp-java-se-7-programmer-ii-certification-guide/)**: PREPARE FOR THE 1ZO-804 EXAM

Comment: Ao inves de ficar copiando o mesmo texto em todas as perguntas não seria mais  interessante explicar qual a sua duvida mais especifica em relação a questão? Lendo as perguntas da a impressão de ser apenas um control+c e control+v desenfreado, mas não uma dúvida concreta.

Comment: @diegofm, o objetivo de copiar a introdução é para garantir que ninguém marque com duplicidade as perguntas e que mantenha  o foco para implementar na prática as respostas. Tipo como esta [minhas resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/194508/6789) mesmo sendo grande tentei deixar bem prático.

Comment: Não acho esse formato legal, parece que as perguntas não levam a um objetivo, que seria esclarecer uma dúvida concreta ou solucionar um problema. Enfim, a pergunta é sua, esta foi só uma dica. Talvez mudando esse formato pra algo mais direto, as perguntas ganhem mais visibilidade e, quem sabe, boas respostas.

Comment: @diegofm, obrigado em contribuir e pela dica. Verdade! Estou trabalhando em outro formato de pergunta. Sem muita firulas e com mais foco. E novamente obrigado! Assim que eu terminar vou editar as perguntas com o novo formato!

Comment: Você quer saber quando a Subclasse deve usar a variável declarada pela Superclasse, e quando a Subclasse deveria sobrescrever esta variável?

Comment: @Douglas, na verdade eu gostaria de uma resposta mais prática mesmo, se possível implementada. Usar os paradigmas OO nem sempre é trivial e simples, o que geralmente vemos na prática implementado nos sistemas são classes com codificação procedural com mais de 30 linhas, com regras de negócio misturadas com códigos de infraestrutura (e-mail, acesso a banco de dados, web sevices). Então, como objetos de classes diferentes compartilham a mesma variável? Responda da forma que preferir! O importante é contribuir!